# Maximal matchings in connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, matching-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a positive integer. Is there a connected graph $G$ such that $G$ cannot be coloured with less than $n$ colours, and every two maximal [matchings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) have non-empty intersection?

(I take maximality with respect to set inclusion.)

Comment: Do you know any such graph with more than two vertices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another attempt. Take $K_{n+1} $ and three paths $abc, ade, afg$, $a\in K_{n+1} $, $b, c, d, e, f, g\notin K_{n+1} $. Any maximal matching contains at most one of edges $ab, ad, af$, thus at least two from three edges $bc, de, fg$. Hence any two maximal matchings have a common edge.

Comment: No, if $K_{2n}=K_4$ has vertices $1, 2, 3, 4$ and you add path $abc$ where $a=1$, the set $\{ab, 23\}$ is a maximal matching that does not contain $bc$.

Comment: Ah, you are right, it is maximal by inclusion though not perfect. My bad.

Comment: Thanks both Keith and Fedor for your exchange of ideas and then the answer!